# yum/repositories is not using sub-folders from source

Tags: centos, yum

I'm pretty much new to centOS. I was using Ubuntu for the last years. But I want to build an production openstack environment and switched os for this purpose. Now i have problems to came along with the yum-installer behaviour.

On my centOS system, there is a source-repository-file /etc /yum.repos.d/CentOS-OpenStack-mitaka.repo.

```
[centos-openstack-mitaka]
name=CentOS-7 - OpenStack mitaka
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/cloud/$basearch/openstack-mitaka/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-Cloud
 (...)
```

I tried to install a package out of the repository, which seems to work just fine, but the package need a specific version of a dependency.

```
Error: Package: 1:python-keystone-9.0.2-1.el7.noarch (centos-openstack-mitaka)
       Requires: python-sqlalchemy >= 1.0.10
       Available: python-sqlalchemy-0.9.8-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           python-sqlalchemy = 0.9.8-1.el7
Error: Package: python2-oslo-db-4.6.0-1.el7.noarch (centos-openstack-mitaka)
       Requires: python-sqlalchemy >= 0.9.9
       Installing: python-sqlalchemy-0.9.8-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           python-sqlalchemy = 0.9.8-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:python-keystone-9.0.2-1.el7.noarch (centos-openstack-mitaka)
       Requires: python-sqlalchemy >= 1.0.10
       Installing: python-sqlalchemy-0.9.8-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           python-sqlalchemy = 0.9.8-1.el7
```

I was looking for this version, and found it. It is in a subfolder of the specific repository, but it is not used. I don't know why the yum-system does not use the subfolder of the repo. (http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/cloud/x86_64/openstack-mitaka/common/python-sqlalchemy-1.0.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm)

Perhaps someone with more experiance with the centOS yum installer can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this strange (for me it's very strange) behaviour. There is a plugin calles 'priority'. This prevent using a package even if the version is newer because of priorities. I could install my package with a disable parameter.

```
--disableplugin=
```

Or even remove (CentOS 7) the plugin with

```
yum remove yum-plugin-priorities
```